# Is Heatmap Color Ramp uniform across different rasters for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, heat-map

I have about 16 rasters spanning the same extent and containing the same variable.

I use the display symbology in ArcGIS to generate a stretched Color Ramp which is the heatmap i want.

As the Colorramp colors adjust to maximum and minimum values within a given raster , does it makes sense to compare two different heatmaps with same colorramp but slightly different statistical distribution ?

Is there a way to generate a heatmap that is independent of statistical distribution and purely a function a variable value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the min and max values manually.  Choose a range that will accomodate all the rasters and set them all to the same min/max values.